# SQL join 2 tables including null results

Tags: sql-server

Table A :

| Id | DateA | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/10/2022 | comm1 |
| 1 | 03/10/2022 | comm2 |
| 2 | 02/10/2022 | comm3 |
| 2 | 03/10/2022 | comm4 |
| 3 | 01/10/2022 | comm5 |
| 3 | 02/10/2022 | comm6 |
| 3 | 03/10/2022 | comm7 |

Table B :

| Id | DateB | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/10/2022 | comm1 |
| 1 | 04/10/2022 | comm10 |
| 1 | 03/10/2022 | comm2 |

My goal :

- Display all data from Table A
- Join table A and table B with the Id and the Date

My problem is that I also want to get record from table B when date in table A is null (record when comment = "comm10" in my exemple)

| Id | DateTableA | DateTableB | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/10/2022 | 02/10/2022 | comm1 |
| 1 | 03/10/2022 | 03/10/2022 | comm2 |
| 1 | null | 04/10/2022 | comm10 |
| 2 | 02/10/2022 | 02/10/2022 | comm3 |
| 2 | 03/10/2022 | 03/10/2022 | comm4 |
| 3 | 01/10/2022 | 01/10/2022 | comm5 |
| 3 | 02/10/2022 | 02/10/2022 | comm6 |
| 3 | 03/10/2022 | 03/10/2022 | comm7 |

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: I confirm, FULL OUTER JOIN is the solution